# Why can't the compiler find the assignment operator?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

```
template <typename T>
class MyPointer
{public:


    template <typename U>
    void operator=(MyPointer<U>&& other)
    {
      
    }
    char* get() const { return pointer; }
private:
    char* pointer;
};

int main()
{
    struct B {};
    struct D : B{};   

    MyPointer<B> my_pointer_b;
    MyPointer<D> my_pointer_d;

    my_pointer_b = my_pointer_d;


}
```

The error I get:

> binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type
> 'MyPointermain::D' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

The compiler instantiates the assignment operator for the particular type that I use, so even if it deleted the default one the instantiated one should be there.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No it doesn't && is a universal reference, not an r-value. It takes both

Comment: `U&&` would be universal ref, `C<U>&&` is not.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen ohhhhh, that's not a universal reference, i would have been if it was U type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the [error with gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/1WerTjKj6) helps to shed more light on this:

```
<source>:24:20: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'MyPointer<main()::D>&&' to lvalue of type 'MyPointer<main()::D>'
   24 |     my_pointer_b = my_pointer_d;
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Your `MyPointer<U>&&` is not a forwarding reference. Its a rvalue reference.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference):

> Forwarding references are a special kind of references that preserve the value category of a function argument, making it possible to forward it by means of `std::forward`. Forwarding references are either:
>
> 1. function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue reference to cv-unqualified type template parameter of that same function template:
> 2. [... auto&& ...]

This is a forwarding reference

```
template <typename T> void foo(T&&);
```

This one is not

```
template <typename T> void bar(X<T>&&);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
template <typename U>
void operator=(MyPointer<U>&& other)
```

In this, `MyPointer<U>&&` is not a forwarding reference. It's an rvalue reference to some `MyPointer<U>`, where `U` is deduced from the argument.

As a result, you cannot call this function with an lvalue.

If you want to use a forwarding reference but constrain it to a `MyPointer` instance, then you can do something like this:

```
// forward declaration
template <typename T>
class MyPointer;

template <typename T>
struct IsMyPointerInstance : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct IsMyPointerInstance<MyPointer<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
concept MyPointerInstance = IsMyPointerInstance<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::value;

template <typename T>
class MyPointer {
public:
    template <typename U> requires MyPointerInstance<U>
    void operator=(U&& other) {
        // ...
    }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1zcPo1sKK)

(or use SFINAE if you can't use concepts)